# What is Unexecpected T_STRING

Tags: php

everytime i try to run this it comes up with this error

Unexpected T String in line 35, 36 , 40

```
mysql_query("UPDATE completed SET offer_id=campid WHERE id ='".$sid."'");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO completed reward) VALUES ".$payout." * 0.5);
mysql_close();
echo "Success: ".$sid." earned ".$payout." * 0.5 points\n and is referred by nobody";
```

There is an error on all lines expect for mysql_close(); and the rest of my code is clean
what is the problem?

Comment: Please paste *the exact error message that you're getting.*  We don't need the whole call stack, just the actual error message.

Comment: You're missing a closing double-quote on your second query.

Comment: On another note, [mysql_query](http://www.php.net/mysql_query) is deprecated, and your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.  Consider using MySQLi or PDO instead.

Answer (score 3):

It means your code had a compilation error. You can see it here on Stack Overflow with the color of the code rendered in your question.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO completed reward) VALUES ".$payout." * 0.5);
```

...should be:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO completed reward) VALUES ".$payout." * 0.5");
```

...or better yet, using PHP's double-quote string substitution:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO completed reward) VALUES $payout * 0.5");
```

This will get you past the compilation error... But I think you need to take a second look at your query. I don't think you meant that closing parenthesis in `INSERT INTO completed reward) VALUES...`

Answer (score 2):

The syntax highlighter shows you exactly where the rrror is. You're missing a quote:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO completed reward) VALUES ".$payout." * 0.5); //
```

ahould be

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO completed reward) VALUES ".$payout." * 0.5");
```